# How to disable Yoxos popups in Eclipse on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, popups

I used the http://eclipsesource.com/en/yoxos/yoxos-ondemand/? tool to build an Eclipse distribution, but they keep giving these annoying Yoxos popups.  I don't even get whether Yoxos is free or paid or just annoying as heck.  How do you get rid of these Yoxos popups?

This is the text of the popup:
POPUP:

Thank you for evaluating Pydev Extensions.

If you wish to license Pydev Extensions, please visit the link below for instructions on how to buy your license:

Buy

When you license it, not only will you get rid of this dialog, but you will also help fostering the Pydev Open Source version.

If you wish more information on the available features, you can check it on the link below:

Features Matrix

Or you may browse the homepage starting at its initial page:

Pydev Extensions Main Page

The links don't allow you to register buy the PyDev extensions.  How can I switch to free pydev extensions?  My other eclipse installs I just used the free PyDev and it is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of popups do you get? In Yoxos 99% of the content available at http://ondemand.yoxos.com is free and/or Open Source.
There are a few commercial thing as well ... For example PyDev Extensions: DyDev itself is free but if you install the PyDev extensions, you'll get pop-ups to get the full license of that component.

Comment: Is there a free version of PyDev extensions to get for Yoxos?  The popup for PyDev extensions doesn't allow me to register/buy replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you report the problem to the Yoxos forums?

http://getsatisfaction.com/eclipsesource/topics/new?topic%5Bproducts%5D=Yoxos+OnDemand

Answer (score 0):

Yoxos OnDemand is a free service provided to the Eclipse user community to help them get up and running with Eclipse. It allows you to choose between ~6000 plug-ins that have been validated for version dependency consistency etc.  You can buy Yoxos Enterprise and install this infrastructure in your own organization to support your entire team with your own plugin content etc. There's a rumor of an inexpensive "professional" version that supports teams and sharing and ... while still being a SaaS offering.  Another dimension is the content. Yoxos SecureSource offers subscriptions to various levels of plugin validation from licensing to viruses and malicious code.  Look for more from the Yoxos team in the coming months.